# ASP.NET MVC3 can't bind a decimal field from a TextBoxFor to my Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model, decimal

This is probably a dummy question, but I'm stuck with a problem I can't resolve by myself.

I'm working on an **ASP.NET MVC3** project. For some reason, on a particular `Create` page, a decimal field is not binded on the model when the page is validated and I can't understand why.
Here is my code :

```
@model ModelA

/*some TextBoxFor or others DropDownListFor, all of them working well*/

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ModelB.ModelC.MyField, new { @id = "txtMyField" })
```

When I validate the page, the model `ModelA` is correctly filled **EXCEPT** for this particular field `MyField`. Others fields are OK, for exemple :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ModelB.AnotherField, new { @id = "txtAnotherField" })
```

perfecly works, and others properties of `ModelB` are correctly filled.

**My models**

`ModelA` contains a property of type `ModelB` called `ModelB`.
`ModelB` contains a property of type `ModelC` called `ModelC`.
`ModelC` contains a property called `MyField`. (I'll probably add one or two more in the future). This field is a `decimal` field, without any DataAnnotation or anything.

```
public decimal MyField { get; set; }
```

By the way, when in my browser's console I request

```
$('#txtMyField').val()
```

it displays the good value, for example `12.54`.

**What I tried**

- Change this decimal field to a float type, the problem is the same.
- Put it in an EditorFor instead of a TextBoxFor, the problem is the same.
- Put the field MyField in ModelB. The only ModelB's property to 0 is MyField.

Why is this field a rebel ? I probably do something wrong, but I can't understand where... Can someone explain me where is my mistake ?
Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried renaming the property? Just to discard for example a collision with a route parameter

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so here is the solution :

A "correct" decimal value looks like 45.68 with a `.` as a separator.
But the application is a non-English application, and the separator need to be a `,`. By default, 45,68 is not a correct number. So I added this piece of code :

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
    number: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
    }
});
```

and 45,68 is recognized as a correct number.

Comment: Easiest & best  way to solve the problem !

THANK YOU A LOT !